# How can I mock a private method in Java 21

Tags: java, mocking, java-21

I am trying to migrate my application from Java 8 to Java 21. I am facing significant obstacles in the UT part. I was using JMockit as my mock framework and was planning to upgrade to Mockito. However, Mockito does not support mocking private methods, which is making my UT upgrade very painful.

Is there any way to mock private methods?

Comment: If you can, redesign your code/tests so that you don't have to mock a private method. Private methods are part of the implementation of public methods. By testing the public API, you are implicitly testing the private method(s).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I test a class that has private methods, fields or inner classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571/how-do-i-test-a-class-that-has-private-methods-fields-or-inner-classes)